# Hook when we do svn add

Tags: svn

I have written a pre-commit hook to restrict a user to add any directory to the existing repository without managers approval.

As the pre-commit hook works only at the time of commit, I wanted to know whether we can check the file type and show the alert when the user does `svn add`.

Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with standard tools. Maybe with an own/patched SVN client.

Some clients/integrations provide client side hooks like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks).

Maybe [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) can help you in some cases. But it's not almighty...